# undefined method data_for for main:object error in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I wrote a small script that try to read data from a .yml file using DataMagic.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'data_magic'

DataMagic.yml_directory="/home/krishna/RUBY/"
DataMagic.load "testdata.yml"

testData = data_for("testdata.yml/Testcase_01")
puts "#{testData[:username]}"
```

when i execute this i am getting an error

```
hashdata.rb:7:in `<main>': undefined method `data_for' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Tell me what i am missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'data_magic'
include DataMagic    
DataMagic.yml_directory="/home/krishna/RUBY/"
testData = data_for("testdata/Testcase_01")
puts "#{testData['username']}"
```